# What is the default limit for auto generated primary Column(Integer) in SQLAlchemy with FastAPI and MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

Currently, I'm using Python's fastAPI with SQLAlchemy and MYSQL. I've defined an auto-generated primary column as shown below. What's the maximum number that this column can hold? Currently, the DB grows by 10k records per day, and I clear 70% of it on the weekends. The number of records will always stay constant, but I want to know the maximum limit that 'id' can hold before breaking down. This 'id' column is important to me, for sorting the results, and I don't want it to overflow somehow.

```
class SampleData(SampleTable):
__tablename__ = 'demotable'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
col1 = Column(String(100))
col2 = Column(String(100))
```

What's the maximum value that the column 'id' can ever hold?

Comment: Thanks, that solves my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value of a signed integer in MySQL (as well as most other programming languages) is 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or 2147483647.

This is documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

If you use 10k id values per day, that will overflow in 214748 days, or just short of 588 years.

If that's not enough, then make your id column a `BIGINT`. Then it will last until after Earth's Sun envelops the Earth.

Comment: @Luuk Your comment is unkind and unnecessary.